# Php function to Send Gcm more than 1000 users

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I have function code to send gcm, it works until token GCM ID have reached more than 1000 users it will not send.

this is my function code.

```
private static function send_message($title,$url){
    global $wpdb;
    $token = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'devices', ARRAY_N );
    foreach ($token as $key) {

        $registrationIds[] = $key[1];
    }               
    $msg = array(
    'registrationIds' => $group,
        'message' => $title,
        'url' => $url,
        'title' => 'This is a title. title',
    );
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
        'data' => $msg
    );
     $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FA_API,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);                   
    curl_close($ch);   
    return $result;
}
```

Please help me how to send push notification more than 1000 users.

Comment: does the api have rate limits

Comment: You might have a limit on how many calls you can make. If this code works, it's not a programming problem.

Comment: yes its must to send with every 1000 users token. its must using loops

Answer (score 1):

> This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or
>   IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at
>   most 1000 registration tokens.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json
GCM limit 1000 device each message.
So you have to split `$registrationIds` array into to smaller arrays. Then sends them away in a loop.